# Computing variance given bivariate normal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose (X, Y ) has a bivariate normal distribution with means equal to zero, standard deviations equal to 1, and a correlation $0.5$. We want to find the variance of $XY$. To do so, I used law of total variance as follows:

$$ Var[XY] = \mathbb{E}[Var[XY|Y]] + Var[\mathbb{E}[XY|Y]]$$
Then, conditioning on the random variable $Y$, we have,
$$ Var[XY] = \mathbb{E}[Var[XY]] + Var[\mathbb{E}[XY]]$$
$$\rightarrow Var[XY] = \mathbb{E}[Y^2Var[X]] + Var[Y\mathbb{E}[X]]$$
$$\rightarrow Var[XY] = \mathbb{E}[Y^2] = Var[Y] + \mathbb{E}[Y]^2 = 1$$

I am going wrong somewhere as the correct answer is 1.25. However, I am not sure where my mistake is.

Comment: $\mathbb E(\mathbb {Var}(XY\mid Y))$ does not generally equal $\mathbb E(\mathbb {Var}(XY))$.  Rather $\Bbb E(\Bbb{Var}(XY\mid Y))=\Bbb E(Y^2\,\Bbb{Var} [X\mid Y])$

Comment: Similarly, $\text{Var}(E[XY \mid Y])$ is not $\text{Var}(E[XY])$ in general; it is $\text{Var}(E[XY \mid Y]) = \text{Var}(YE[X \mid Y])$.

Comment: I see. Is this not true: $\mathbb{E}[Var[XY|Y=y]] =\mathbb{E}[Var[Xy]] = \mathbb{E}[y^2Var[X]] $?

Comment: No.  Because $X$ is dependent on the value of $Y$.  $\mathsf {Var}(XY\mid Y=y)=y^2\,\mathsf {Var}(X\mid Y=y)$